# Windows Defender recognize output binary of C# desktop project release build with Visual Studio 2019 as Trojan

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, antivirus, windows-defender

I use VS 2019 16.6.0 and build my project in **Release** configuration with these settings:

[image: VS 2019 advanced build settings]

My result binary will recognized as Trojan:MSIL/Fareit.VM!MTB:

[image: Trojan:MSIL/Fareit.VM!MTB]

**Get-MpComputerStatus** executed in PowerShell:

```
AMEngineVersion                 : 1.1.17100.2
AMProductVersion                : 4.18.2004.6
AMServiceEnabled                : True
AMServiceVersion                : 4.18.2004.6
AntispywareEnabled              : True
AntispywareSignatureAge         : 0
AntispywareSignatureLastUpdated : 29.05.2020 16:06:44
AntispywareSignatureVersion     : 1.317.207.0
AntivirusEnabled                : True
AntivirusSignatureAge           : 0
AntivirusSignatureLastUpdated   : 29.05.2020 16:06:44
AntivirusSignatureVersion       : 1.317.207.0
BehaviorMonitorEnabled          : True
ComputerID                      : AFCC7D96-94CF-402C-BC3E-9ECE1640D1A0
ComputerState                   : 0
FullScanAge                     : 4294967295
FullScanEndTime                 :
FullScanStartTime               :
IoavProtectionEnabled           : True
IsTamperProtected               : True
IsVirtualMachine                : False
LastFullScanSource              : 0
LastQuickScanSource             : 2
NISEnabled                      : True
NISEngineVersion                : 1.1.17100.2
NISSignatureAge                 : 0
NISSignatureLastUpdated         : 29.05.2020 16:06:44
NISSignatureVersion             : 1.317.207.0
OnAccessProtectionEnabled       : True
QuickScanAge                    : 6
QuickScanEndTime                : 23.05.2020 14:27:29
QuickScanStartTime              : 23.05.2020 14:25:44
RealTimeProtectionEnabled       : True
RealTimeScanDirection           : 0
PSComputerName                  :
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting Debug info to **Embedded** resolves it

[image: Visual Studio Advanced Build Settings Debugging Information]